# vb.net wince connect to wireless network

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have an application using the wince compact framework in vb.net and I now need it to connect to a specified wireless network on the click of a button, I have done alot of research on this and I have even got fully commented working code using the wlanapi.dll however I have just found this API is not in the compact framework.

Does anyone know if its possible to get the wlanapi.dll onto the compact framework or anyone out there with knowledge on the WirelessZeroConfigNetworkInterface which I am guessing is my next step.
I have found the following:
http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/08/19/AServiceForScanningAndConnectingToWiFiNetworksFromTheCF.aspx
This looks great but I have no idea how I would integrate this with my vb.net code.

Anyone out there with any ideas - Im feeling a little out of my comfort zone!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wlanapi.dll is a desktop windows binary.  It will not work under Windows CE, and there is no analogous file in CE available.  For CE 5.0 and 6.0, you have to use the WZC APIs, assuming the adapter you want to work with is WZC compliant - not all are.  For CE 7.0 you have to use the Native WiFi APIs (thanks Microsoft, that was a genius move).

The link you show above is some service code that wraps the OpenNETCF Smart Device Framework (SDF) WiFi classes, which in turn wrap the WZC APIs.

The way to "integrate" that service code is probably to just rewrite it in VB.NET - there's really not much code there.  Of course you'd still need to add a reference to the SDF binaries.

Comment: For now i have used an online convertor to alter the wrapper hoping that works! I guess then just add OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation dll. great website by the way dude. im going to submit it to mine at http://www.listacker.com

Comment: oh I guess that dll is not part of the standard download for opennetcf damn :(

Comment: Yes, it's part of the normal SDF download.  it's all in the OpenNETCF.Net.dll assembly.  Remember, assembly names don't have to match namespace names.  You'll also have to reference OpenNETCF.dll and maybe OpenNETCF.COnfiguration.dll as well.

Comment: excellent - thank you I will give this a try over the weekend!